# How to add average line per group in seaborns

Tags: python, histogram, data-visualization, seaborn

I have the graph below:

[image: graph image]

created with the following code

```
subset1=data1[feats_to_explore+['wine_class']]
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(7,14), sharey=True)

l=[ax1,ax2,ax3]

for graph in l:
    for i in (subset1['wine_class']).unique():
        df =subset1[subset1.wine_class == i]
        sns.distplot(df[feats_to_explore[l.index(graph)]],  kde=False, label=i, ax=graph)
        graph.legend(title='Wine Class')
```

I would like to add, for each histogram, an average line of the same color than the respective histogram. In other words, three lines per each subplot.

May somebody help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `plt.axvline` call:

```
for graph in l:
    for i in (subset1['wine_class']).unique():
        df =subset1[subset1.wine_class == i]
        plt.axvline(df[feats_to_explore[l.index(graph)]].mean())  ## Here
        sns.distplot(df[feats_to_explore[l.index(graph)]],  kde=False, label=i, ax=graph)
        graph.legend(title='Wine Class')
```

Your syntax for the variable you're plotting is a bit weird, so I'm not sure if what I wrote will call the mean of your group, so feel free to replace `df[feats_to_explore[l.index(graph)]].mean()` with whichever syntax calls the mean of the group you're plotting.